# Getting a reference to a Kotlin function as a Java Method

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

I have a Java method that takes a `Method` parameter:

```
void doSomethingWithMethod(Method m) {
    ...
}
```

And I have a Kotlin class that contains a function:

```
class MyClass {

    fun myFunction() : List<Something> {
        ...
    }

}
```

I can get a reference to the function with `MyClass::myFunction`, but I don't see a way to pass it into the `doSomethingWithMethod` method. Is there an equivalent to the `.java` property that can be applied to a Kotlin class reference to get its Java equivalent?

If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.javaMethod

val method = MyClass::myFunction.javaMethod
```

The `javaMethod` property is not part of the standard Kotlin library, but is part of the official `kotlin-reflect.jar`. It can be added through Maven with the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The javaMethod property is part of the kotlin-reflect.jar which isn't the same as the standard library. While I was aware that there was a reflection library, seeing that javaClass was part of the standard library made me assume that javaMethod would be too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard java reflection to get `Method` in kotlin:

```kotlin
MyClass::class.java.getMethod("myFunction")
```

or

```kotlin
MyClass::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("myFunction")
```

Need no dependencies to do so.

Docs:
[Method getMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...))
[Method getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...))